# Re-apply a slide layout to existing slides

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I have a PowerPoint presentation where the odd-numbered slides have master layout A, and the even numbered slides have master layout B (with a few exceptions that I can sort manually). When I update one of the layouts (e.g. adding or moving placeholders), I have to manually select every other slide to re-apply the layout to them. How can I automatically re-apply the layout to these slides?

If there is no built-in feature to do this (or even if there is!) a macro would be just as useful.

Comment: I'm not a regular here, so wasn't quite sure how to tag it. If it's tagged wrong please fix it! :-)

Comment: Your tags are relevant - no problem, but I think you don't even need to use macros... simply check "apply to all slides" option in the toolbar. Also if you want to discuss code, post in www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @AnandS I don't want to discuss code, because then I'd be falling foul of the XY problem, and "gimme teh codez" questions are not appreciated there (or here, but this isn't quite one). And I don't want the "apply to all slides" option; I only want to apply it to slide 4 and every other slide after and including 7.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! And I believe you have misunderstood me - I'm not urging you to blatantly ask for the full code, but rather requesting you to move this question to Stack Overflow, as this is about coding...

Comment: @AnandS I had hoped that there was a built-in feature to let me do this. They all already have the right slide layout; I just want to re-apply it to the ones that already have it, as per https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-a-slide-layout-489A23C6-7170-455E-BB88-CF5D6F09D990

Comment: You do understand that you can select the slides you want in Slide Sorter view by control+clicking, then use Home | Slides | Layout to apply the layout you want, right?  A bit tedious, but for a one-shot, a lot faster than looking for/writing code to do the job.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I understand that, but I'll be doing this several times. I have already done that twice :-]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To re-apply the current slide layout to a slide, right click on the slide and select "Reset Slide" from the context menu. You can select ranges of slides, or even the whole presentation, from the left-hand pane. This will re-apply the layout for all slides, not just for specified ones, but each slide will retain its existing layout.

Answer (score 1):

Since there aren't normally 32 layouts in a presentation design, I'm assuming you have a custom layout.  In any case, try this, substituting the correct number for 2 below:

```
Sub ReapplyMaster()
    Dim slidenum As Long
    For slidenum = 3 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count Step 2
        With ActivePresentation.Slides(slidenum)

            .CustomLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2)

        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I've changed the question to remove the macro, but that doesn't invalidate your answer. Would `.CustomLayout = .CustomLayout` work?

Comment: It'd be faster to give it a try than to wait for an answer here, no?

Comment: Do you think I should accept your answer (shows a lot of effort and is extensible) or the answer I posted (is a built-in feature, more useful for non-power users)?

Comment: Since this is SuperUser and not StackOverflow, I'd go with your own answer (which is more or less like the suggestion I made earlier).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll just wait 22 hours before accepting, just because I feel like it and definitely not because the system has a >48-hour restriction.